# Fetch Username from Lookup-Column using Powershell-PNP

Tags: pnp-powershell

I am trying to retrieve the actual username from a lookup column, the closest I got is

```
$test=(Get-PnPListItem -List $list -Fields Owner -Id 1).FieldValues
```

This of course returns the value as `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I will answer my own question just in case it's useful for others.

First we need to pull the list item:

```
$listitem=(Get-PnPListItem -List "TestList" -id $itemid).FieldValues
```

Then pick the column where the user information is stored and get the email back:

```
$team_lead_email=$listitem["TeamLeader"].Email
```

If the field has multiple entries we have to loop through the entries:

```
$users=$listitem["TeamMembers"].Email


foreach ($User in $Users) { 
    Add-PnPUserToGroup -LoginName $User -Identity "$Team Members"
}
```